# End 'If Statement' with Function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to basically pass over the rest of an if statement once a function is run to determine a certain value to be 0 or 1. If the value is 0, It passes the rest of the if statement, if it's 1, it continues with the if statement it's in and run accordingly. Here's the code:

```
test2.py

import os, sys
from functiontest import function

message = 'foo'
check = 0

if 'foo' in message:
    check = function(message,check)
    print(check)
    print('bar')

if check == 0:
    print('foo not recognized')
```

with the function file being

```
functiontest.py

import os, sys

def function(a,b):
    print('checking message')
    a = a.split()
    print(a)
    if a[0] == 'foo':
        b = 1
        print(b)
        return b
    else:
        b = 0
        return b
```

When a word other than "foo" exactly as written is detected, it should only output "foo not recognized". With a word like "foot", it still runs the code within the if statement because it contains foo, which I don't want it to. Is there a way to pass over the rest of the if statement from the function side? I know how to do it with an if else statement in the main test2.py code because I pass back the check argument, but I'm looking to make the main code as clean as possible, so is there a way to accomplish that within functiontest.py? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe instead test for `if message == 'foo'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved by doing what is suggested in: [How to exit an if clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069662/how-to-exit-an-if-clause)

Not clear to me is this will solve your issue but this would be my code:

```
import os, sys

def check_message(message):
    print('Checking message')
    for m in message.split():
        if m == 'foo':
            return True
        else:
            return False


def wrapper(message):
    if 'foo' in message:
        check = check_message(message)
        if check:
            return
        print(check)
        print('bar')


message = 'foo'
wrapper(message)
```

but I don't understand why the double check on the message and not just:

```
def wrapper(message):
    if check_message(message)
        return
    print('bar')


message = 'foo'
wrapper(message)
```

In this case, `'bar'` will be printed only if the message does not container `'foo'` words.

Also, regarding your code, you don't need to give `check` as an input, since you are not using it in the `function` function, you overwrite it in any case.

It's also better to use `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0`

Comment: That works, much appreciated! Reason I do a double check on it is because I plan to use it to allow inputs after 'foo', so like example the message could be 'foo 5' and I would split it into a list and use that 5 for something :)