# Why can I not "exit" my nested if else statement (Python)?

Tags: python, if-statement, nested-loops

I am trying to break out of an if statement within a function, but it is not behaving as I expect. I am following answers on this previous SO question, [How to exit an if clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069662/how-to-exit-an-if-clause/2090603), specifically the top rated answer.

**Here is the code:**

```
import random

def logic_function():
    if 1 == 0:
        random_number = random.randint(10, 20)
        return random_number
    return

def number_function(foo):
    if foo == 1:
        number = logic_function()
        print(number)
    elif foo == 2:
        number = 2
        print(number)
    else:
        print('Nothing will happen')

print(number_function(1))
```

**What I expect:**

I have a function, `number_function`, where a number is inputted as a parameter. If the parameter is 1, then the generated number uses a function called `logic_function` to generate a random number between 10 and 20, if `1 == 0`. 1 will not be equal to 0, so I expect the the return at the end of the `logic_function` to be called and I go into the outer if else statements within `number_function`, specifically the `else` statement at the end where `Nothing Will Happen` is printed.

Current output for `print(number_function(1))` is:

```
None
None
```

I expect it to be:

`Nothing Will Happen`

I am also curious why that second `None` is being printed. Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: In your example, the program behaves exactly as it should: You set `foo==1` in your function call. So, the first condition of your if-block is true and the `logic_function` is called. This function can only return `None` as 1 never is equal to 0. This `None` is printed. Then, you print the result of the `number_function()`, which is `None` because this function does not return anything. That's where the two `None` come from.

Comment: Your code has some inaccuracy .
if 1 == 0:
This will always be False so none will come everytime .
Try to wrestle with problems more.

Comment: This is a very strange question. When `foo == 1`, then whatever is indented under `if foo == 1:` is executed. What does `logic_function` have to do with any of this?

Comment: "so I expect the the return at the end of the logic_function to be called **and I go into the outer if else statements within number_function**" <- why do you expect the bolded part to happen?

Comment: @timgeb This is where I had issues, I do not know if I have to explicitly tell the statement to break and go to the outer `else`. This can be done in a `while` with `break`, but this is not a `while` loop, so I am uncertain how to approach this.

Comment: If makes zero sense to go into the `else` block of an `if foo == 1: ... / else: ...` statement when `foo` is equal to one.

Comment: @timgeb Thank you for the feedback, I am trying to learn why this would make "zero sense". I assumed I would go to the outer `else` because conditions within the `logic_function` are not being met, I am now realizing this is not the case.

Comment: The test you are performing in order to decide whether to go into the `if` or `else` block is `foo == 1`. There is no other test. `logic_function` is completely irrelevant for testing which block to enter.

Answer (score 0):

You're assumptions are wrong. First of all the function `logic_function` will always return `None`. As `1 == 0` is always `False`, you could just simplify it to:

```
def logic_function():
    return
```

Second, if you have an `if-elif-else` construct, you will always run into *one single* branch, i.e. you won't execute the statements in the `if` part **and** the statements in the `else` parts. That's not possible.

You're program prints `None` twice, because you have one `print` inside the `if` branch and one after the whole `if-elif-else` construct.

As you seem to not understand basic python concepts, I recommend you to make some tutorials about it, e.g. [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
def logic_function():
    return

def number_function(foo):
    if foo == 1:
        number = logic_function()
        print(number)
    else:
        print('Nothing will happen')

print(number_function(1))
```

I removed some unnecesary code.

your `number_function` doesn't return anything. So if you print that it will be `None`.
You supply the function with a 1. So your `logic_function` will be executed. That function returns `None`. Which you save in the variable `number` which is then printed.

So it's logical for your code to print `None` twice. It will not print `Nothing Will Happen` because the condition `foo == 1` evaluates to `True`.